# understanding indexs with a simple select query

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization

I'm trying to understand how to properly work with indexes with basic queries.

example:

I have the table 'testme' with the following columns:

```
id int primary key
username varchar(20)
data1 int
data2 int
data3 int
data_order int
```

if i do

```
select username,data1,data2 from testme where data3=5 order by data_order;
```

which kind of indexes i can use to speed up the query ?

i tried adding an index on clumns data3 and data_order but the result of 'explain' to that query shows that it doesn't use that index.

update:
 using mysql cluster (ndb)

Comment: How large is your table? I'm not sure about MySQL, but in many RDBMSs it is quicker to access relatively small tables (typically fewer than around 100,000 rows) by table scans rather than by indexes.

Comment: this table is very small actually but this query showed up on my slow queries log

Comment: a BTREE index on `(data3, data_order)` as @Dems suggests should be the best.

Answer (score 2):

for this specific query there are two indexes which will help -

Index on data3 ( Hash if you are sure that there will be only queries with data3 equals something, otherwise use btree ) and index on data_order ( btree )

EDIT: In this case separate indexes are better, because AFAIK mysql not always search for composite index for where and order statement, and another problem is, that later you cannot use only order using this index ( index will be for data3 + data_order or only for data3 as mysql read indexes from leftmost column )

Comment: what do you think about having a single index for both columns?

Comment: This will not work, because single index is good when you have both fields in where statement

Comment: Are you sure, it means that index will not be used when you have a composite index containing other columns?

Comment: hash indexes can only be unique indexes so this is not an option. gonna try btree

Comment: It not takes any column from composite index, but it will start by leftmost column, so if you have composite index on ( foo, bar ) and in where statement there will be foo and bar it is ok, but this index will not work if you have only bar. and it is not good practice to mix indexes for where and for order by ( during to the fact mysql can search for where and order statement indexes separately )

Comment: @SergeS - Do you have any references or evidence for that last part?  `it is not good practice to mix indexes for where and for order by`.  I would suggest that in this case a composite index really is the best option.

Comment: it is my practice, any time i done composite index for this prupuose, on some queries it fails ... so this is AFIAK ( see edited post )

Answer (score 2):

Think of an Index as two things...
1. The order in which data is stored
2. A quick way to lookup specific pieces of data (like a book index)

In your example, having an index on `(data3, data_order)` will make it very easy to find the data you want, and already have it in the correct order.

It still needs to go to the table after searching the index, to get fields `username, data1, data2`.  For this reason you may `include` them in the index as well.  This makes the index bigger, using more space and slightly more effort to update.  But that cost means the index isn't being *joined* to the table.  It's just reading the index.

Answer (score 1):

The best index for the case (actually depends on table size and cardinality of date3):

```
CREATE INDEX yourindex ON yourtable(Data3, Data_order)
INCLUDE(username, data1, data2)
```

or if mysql does not support including columns

```
CREATE INDEX yourindex ON yourtable(Data3, Data_order, username, data1, data2)
```

Why best?

- filters by direct `date3` value
- orders by `data_order` value
- includes all you need for select list (covering index) (if mysql supports including columns)

**Update:**

For **small** tables the optimizer may choose to use table scan instead of index.

**The more** data in your table, **the more likely* indexes will be used, especially if cardinality of index is high enough

Comment: What is `INCLUDE` in your example? It does not seem to be supported by MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html

Comment: `ASC` in the index definition makes people incorrectly think that `DESC` might make sence. Unfortunatelly, it is not true for MySQL yet.

Comment: this just provides an error, the syntax doesn't show that create index command has include parameter.

Comment: explain shows that index in possible_keys but doesn't actually use it